# functors of string diagrams in a monoidal category

Tags: ct.category-theory

Hi,

If I have a string diagram, can I take its functor easily by drawing a new string diagram and just say the wires go to wires and boxes go to boxes?

Comment: I'm not following. If string diagrams are thought of as representing morphisms in a freely generated monoidal category or 2-category of some sort (generated by a tensor scheme, or by a computad), call it $Free(S)$, then a monoidal functor $F: Free(S) \to M$ into another monoidal category will interpret the string diagram as a morphism in $M$. But I don't know what "its functor" is. Are you considering the case where $M = Free(S)$, so that the values of $F$ are string diagrams again? 

Comment: Don't you need the functor to preserve the appropriate structure? (Monoidal, etc.)

Comment: Hey, sorry.  I was really hasty here.  "It's functor" is bad language and I will quickly explain. I am trying to think of functors as mapping diagrams to diagrams.  This is true in normal presentations of diagrams where dots are objects and arrows are morphisms.  Any diagram in $A$, under $F:A \rightarrow B$ will map to a similarly shaped diagram in $B$.  So, one can think very locally about functors in terms of just what a diagram shape gets mapped to.

I was thinking this would all be true when working with string diagram presentations of "diagrams" eek.


Comment: Todd,
My particular example is a frobenius algebra, or comonoid category, $C$ in a symmetric monoidal category, $X$.  The comonoid category is defined as $(A, \f,\g)$ where $A$ is an object in $X$ and $\f, \g $ are 
$f: A \rightarrow \A \otimes \A$ 
$g: A \rightarrow \A \otimes I$
So, a forgetful functor $F: C \rightarrow X$ just forgets the extra morphisms and gives $A$.  Both categories $X$ and $C$ have string diagrams and I want to know what a string diagram becomes under $F$.  So this is very similar to what you have suggested where $M = Free(S)$ where $S$ is a symmetric monoidal cat.



Comment: sorry about superfluous "\" slashes


Comment: Qiaochu,
  Yes, I was thinking of functor as we all know it in that it maps identity to identity and composition to composition.  This is why I think any string diagram will be a string diagram under any functor.

Comment: http://www.pps.univ-paris-diderot.fr/~mellies/papers/functorial-boxes.pdf

is this what you're looking for ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, string diagram indeed has some functorial  properties, see for example my draft paper: Combinatorics and algebra of tensor calculus, https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.01790